# Please troubleshoot error message I am facing during following getting started - Download Platform-specific Binaries

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I tried this below,

```
$ curl -sSL https://some_shortened_url | bash
```

The shortened URL can be found under Download Platform-specific Binaries section of http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#binaries

The shortened URL is as shown below:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.0.sh

I get this output messages below. Seems like there were errors:

> ===> Downloading platform binaries   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 22.1M  100 22.1M    0     0  1006k      0  0:00:22  0:00:22
>   --:--:-- 1078k
>   ===> Pulling fabric Images
>   ==> FABRIC IMAGE: peer
>
> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/ error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/images/create?fromImage=hyperledger%2Ffabric-peer&tag=x86_64-1.0.0: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/images/hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0/tag?repo=hyperledger%2Ffabric-peer&tag=latest: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
>   ==> FABRIC IMAGE: orderer

I tried this from Git Bash shell of Windows 10.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you using Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox?  I don't believe that Docker for Windows has has the Docker Quickstart Terminal but Docker Toolbox does.  I've successfully used Git Bash with Docker for Windows on Windows 10 and I use the Docker Quickstart Terminal with Docker Toolbox on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved when I tried same thing on Docker Quickstart Terminal.
Originally I tried on Git Bash.
The procedure seems to be supposed to try on Docker Quickstart Terminal.

I wish this be addressed on the original document.

Comment: we're updating the documentation to add some guidance about this situation, and others that are specific to windows.